# Is there a CSV Scanning with No line found in.nextLine();

Tags: java, csv, pojo, scanning

I have to work with CSV file but i dont need the first line, i tried 
to use: `be.nextLine()` it worked with other project but not with this one. `Scanner be = new Scanner(new File("autok.csv"))`

There is a CSV file i working with looks like this:

First line: | Departure | Destination | Number |     Tel    | room |
Second line:|  Budapest |    Moscow   | PQA-209| 30/5555555 |  5   |
Third line  |  Budapest |   Berlin    | ASD-444| 30/4444855 |  3   |

This is what i tried and worked perfectly with other projects:

````
static ArrayList<autok> kocsi = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
  try (Scanner be = new Scanner(new File("autok.csv"))){
  be.nextLine();
  while(be.hasNextLine()){
      String[] s = be.nextLine().split(";");
      autok d;
      d = new autok(s[0],s[1],s[2],
                    Integer.parseInt(s[3]),
                    Integer.parseInt(s[4]));
      kocsi.add(d);
  }
  }catch (IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("Hiba");
  }

int  asd = kocsi.size();
for(int i =0; i<asd;i++){
    System.out.println("hirdetők száma: " + kocsi.size());
}

}```
````

POJO:

```
        this.indulas = indulas;
        this.cel = cel;
        this.rendszam = rendszam;
        this.telefonszam = telefonszam;
        this.ferohely = ferohely;
    }
    private String indulas;
    private String cel;
    private String rendszam;
    private int telefonszam;
    private int ferohely;
```

and the GETTERS.

As it looks i want to work with this CSV but it gives back the error: 
 `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found` for the : `be.nextLine();`
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Isn't that pretty easy in Java?

Comment: Are those *First Line*, *Second Line* and so on in the file or is it just a description?

Comment: Are you sure the file isn't empty?

Comment: They are just description, and of course it isnt empty, i other project with the same method but this dont want to work.

Answer (score 0):

Working fine `be.nextLine();` but your code need some upgrade

```
static ArrayList<autok> kocsi = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner be = new Scanner(new File("src/com/test/autok.csv"))) {
        be.nextLine();
        while (be.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] s = be.nextLine().split("\\|");

            autok d;
            d = new autok(s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], Integer.parseInt(s[5].trim()));
            kocsi.add(d);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Hiba");
    }

    int asd = kocsi.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < asd; i++) {
        System.out.println("hirdetk szma: " + kocsi.size());
    }

}
```

Class Autok

```
public class Autok {

private String indulas;
private String cel;
private String rendszam;
private String telefonszam;
private int ferohely;

public Autok(String indulas, String cel, String rendszam, String s, int ferohely) {
    this.indulas = indulas;
    this.cel = cel;
    this.rendszam = rendszam;
    this.telefonszam = s;
    this.ferohely = ferohely;
}

// getter & setter
}
```

CSV File

```
| Departure | Destination | Number | Tel | room |
| Budapest | Moscow | PQA-209| 30/5555555 | 5 |
| Budapest | Berlin | ASD-444| 30/4444855 | 3 |
```